# Trying to run Hash.to_xml, but Ruby complains?

Tags: ruby

I'm just trying to run a very simple snippet on my RVM Ruby 1.9.2 installation:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support'

obj = {"foo" => "bar"}
xml = obj.to_xml
```

Ruby complains as follows:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_xml' for {"foo"=>"bar"}:Hash
from (irb):2
from /Users/.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Why is this happening? Isn't to_xml a method of Hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

require this:

```
require "active_support/all"
```